# Confusing with Having query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I am using sql server management studio 2012 and have to make a query to show  which subject a student has failed(condition for failing is point<5.0) the most for the first time from this table

```
StudentID | SubjectID | First/Second_Time | Point.
 1        |   02      |         1         |   5.0 
 2        |   04      |         2         |   7.0
 3        |   03      |         2         |   9      
... etc
```

Here are my teacher's query:

```
SELECT SubjectID
FROM Result(NAME OF the TABLE)
WHERE [First/Second_Time] = 1 AND Point < 5
GROUP BY SubjectID
HAVING count(point) >= ALL 
(
    SELECT count(point)
    FROM Result
    WHERE [First/Second_Time] = 1 AND point < 5
    GROUP BY SubjectID
)
```

I don't understand the reason for making the having query. Because `Count(point)` is always `>=all(select count(point)
from Result
where First/Second_Time=1 and point<5
group by SubjectID)`, isnt it ?
and it doesn't show that the subject has most student fail for the first time. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you on mysql or sql-server?

Comment: i am on sql-server

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. If you're using SQL Server, then don't add tags for other DBMS like MySQL. Tags are meaningful here - add only the ones that are actually relevant to your question. Don't just grab those that sound like something you've heard before. If you're not sure whether the tag applies, read the description of the tag. If you're still not sure, don't add it; someone here will add it for you if it's needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery is returning a list of the number of times a subject was failed (on the first attempt).  It might be easier for you to see what it's doing if you run it like this:

```
SELECT SubjectID, count(point)
    FROM Result
    WHERE [First/Second_Time] = 1 AND point < 5
    GROUP BY SubjectID
```

So if someone failed math twice and science once, the subquery would return:

```
2
1
```

You want to know which subject was failed the most (in this case, which subject was failed 2 or more times, since that is the highest number of failures in your subquery).  So you count again (**also grouping by subject**), and use `having` to return only subjects with 2 or more failures (greater than or equal to the highest value in your subquery).

```
SELECT SubjectID
FROM Result
WHERE [First/Second_Time] = 1 AND Point < 5
GROUP BY SubjectID
HAVING count(point)...
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are working on a project for a class, so I'm not even sure I should answer this, but here goes.  The question is why the having clause.  Have you read the descriptions for [having](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) and [all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) ?

All "Compares a scalar value with a single-column set of values". 
The scalar value in this case is count(point) or the number of occurrences of a subject id with point less than 5.  The single-column set in this case is a list of the number of occurrences of every subject that has less than 5 points.

The net result of the comparison is in the ">=".  "All" will only evaluate to true if it is true for every value in the subquery.  The subquery returns a set of counts of all subjects meeting  the <5 and 1st time requirement.  If you have three subjects that meet the <5 and 1st time criteria, and they have a frequency of 1,2,3 times respectively, then the main query will have three "having" results; 1,2,3.  Each of the main query results has to be >= each of the subquery results for that main value to evaluate true.  So going through step by step, First main value 1 is >= 1, but isn't >= 2 so 1 drops because the "having" is false.  Second main value 2 is >=1, is >= 2, but is not >= 3 so it drops.  Third value, 3, evaluates true as >= 1, 2, and 3, so you end up returning the subject with the highest frequency.

This is fairly clear in the "remarks" section of the MSDN discussion of "All" keyword, but not as relates to your specific application.

Remember, MSDN is our friend!

Comment: Absolutely... select top 1 order by count... You could probably accomplish the same task using max in the subquery (pretty sure I've done that before), but I assumed by the "Here's my teachers query" comment that you are being pointed to the all function

Comment: SELECT top 1 SubjectID
FROM Result(NAME OF the TABLE)
WHERE [First/Second_Time] = 1 AND Point < 5
GROUP BY SubjectID
ORDER BY Count(Point) desc